# What is the preferred method of zero-initializing memory allocated by global operator new?

Tags: c++11, winapi, memory-management

To refresh my rusty C++ knowledge, I've started writing a cross-platform library which interfaces with older win32 APIs. Occasionally, I need to dynamically allocate blocks of memory and cast them to FAM (flexible array member) structs. In trying to adhere to suggested C++ practices, I've opted to use global `::operator new` and `::operator delete`.

I've been able to find example usages of the operators; but what is the recommended (and portable) method of zero-initializing memory allocated this way?

Based on observations of other posts in SO:

1. `std::calloc()` & `std::memset()` should only be used with the related family of functions (`std::malloc()`, `std::realloc()`, etc)
2. To my knowledge, `ZeroMemory()` is platform-specific
3. I've seen examples of `std::fill()` & `std::fill_n()` for arrays and containers; I don't recall ever seeing them used for memory blocks pointed to by `void*`; maybe there is a reason for this.

I've only just begun using global `operator new` & `operator delete`, so my underlying assumptions about how they work and when they should be used may be incomplete as well.

Comment: `memset` is a good tool for when you have a raw block of uninitialized memory. It doesn't have to be paired with `malloc`.

Comment: You don't need this.  `new char[34]();` (with parenthesis!) will automatically zero initialize.

Comment: When dealing with Win32 API structures that are variable-length, you would usually have to dynamically allocate a fixed array of bytes (using `new byte[]` or `std::vector<byte>` will suffice), and then type-cast the starting address of the array to a pointer of the structure type.  In this manner, you can use `byte* buffer = new byte[size]()` (note the parenthesis) or `std::vector<byte> buffer(size, 0)` to pre-fill the byte array with zeros. Though `std::memset()` would be more efficient since it is optimized, whereas the other approaches use byte-by-byte initializations instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `std::vector(size,value)` may call `memset()` internally. Indeed, STL that comes with VC++ implements it like this: `_Uninit_alloc_fill_n1(_First, _Count, _Val, _Al, _Conjunction_t<decltype(_Fill_memset_is_safe(_First, _Val)), _Uses_default_construct< /*bla*/ >>())`

Comment: ... which calls `memset()` if `vector::value_type` is suitable for `memset`.

Comment: Just for completeness: SecureZeroMemory (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: When the memory is already allocated via global operator new, it seems the general consensus is to use `std::memset()`. The other comments help with initial zeroing of the memory block. All of these comments have been insightful and helpful!